# Black screen on wake up with lenovo yoga 2 pro

Tags: 16.04, lenovo, screen, sensors

I closed the lid today to get my laptop to sleep (as usual). Then tonight I opened it again and the screen doesn't light up (it is not a brightness adjustment issue) The computer seems to be working well and I can even connect to it with ssh over the wifi and tried an update in case it was a driver issue.

So it seems to be related to the screen (dead ?) or to one of the lid sensor that make it think it's still closed. The yoga 2 pro has magnetic stuff to maintain it closed and it might be related.

Any clue on how to diagnose the sensors state before declaring the screen dead?

Some context: laptop is <2 years old, running ubuntu 16.04. Output from "sudo dmesg" is [here](https://framabin.org/?59d83129cfb8924c#u30/mH5KVKdrEvJZHiuQKfRBJXTPjvO11H1sO5UGugs=)

Comment: Not really a complete solution (ie the exact issue is still not completely known) but it's fixed after a complete drain of energy (removing main and internal bios batteries) and few restart with power cord.